# Processing an "if" statement within a "do"

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, do-while

I'm trying to get avatars to return within a "do" loop. The avatar pulls from /user/username/avatar.jpg and links to the users profile, unless the avatar field is null, in which it returns a default avatar which links to the users profile.

My code is returning the appropriate profiles upon search. However, when 3 profiles are returned and displayed during the loop, only the first one shows an avatar. The other two only show the "alt image tag" (i.e., the username) as a link to the profile. The image will not appear on any but the first record returned.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Here is the code in question:

```
<?php do { ?>
<p><?php if($avatar == NULL)
{
echo '<a href="profile.php?u='.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"><img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"></a>';
}
else if($avatar != NULL)
{
echo '<a href="profile.php?u='.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"><img src="user/'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;"></a>';
} ?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Edited to add:

OK... this is weird. I echoed $avatar in the repeating field. Apparently, the avatar result 757655830.jpg, which is the file name in the "avatar" field in my table for the FIRST record returned is showing up for EACH record. It is repeating the same avatar information over and over again for each subsequent record and I'm not sure why. All of the other information in each subsequent record is correct.

Comment: Where are you updating `$avatar` ?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to set `$avatar` somewhere inside the loop?

Comment: $avatar = $row_Recordset1["avatar"];

Comment: You should probably change `if($avatar != NULL)` to `if($avatar !== NULL` or `if(is_null($avatar))`.

Comment: It's being called in the query. It will returned the field in the database that names the image in the images folder, i.e. 799230026.jpg  It's returning fine, it just isn't showing up the 2nd and third times in the loop. I hope this is enough information?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally have something like this (I'm assuming you are setting `$avatar` with a column from your database, which is what my code is based around:

```
$Recordset1 = mysql_query("QUERY");

while ($Row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)){
    if ($Row_Recordset1['Avatar'] === null){            
        echo '<a href="profile.php?u='.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"><img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"></a>';
    }elseif ($Row_Recordset1['Avatar'] !== null) {
        echo '<a href="profile.php?u='.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"><img src="user/'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;"></a>';
    }

}
```

If I have assumed incorrectly, feel free to correct me

---

On another note, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions for new code. These functions are depreciated and will be removed in the future revisions of PHP, look into MySQLi or PDO for a new, and more secure API

Comment: Do ou really need the `else if` part? Wouldn't a simple `else` be enough?

Comment: @insertusernamehere The example I have given, was with making minimal change to the inner-loop code it's self, to make it sorta clearer to the OP, on the changes. But the `else if` is not necessary and just a normal `else` condition will work just the same

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver MX to program, because I haven't learned coding well enough to do these complex parts by hand. The DO statement is at the top (and this code is within it) and the WHILE statement is at the bottom. How can I insert this above the WHILE statement (please see original code). Thanks!

Comment: @user2672667 Where the `mysql_query` is, replace the current text with your query to pull data from your database. As I said, i'm guessing that `avatar` is stored with the user information in the database, So Just replace `QUERY` with your actual query, drop this in place of your `do` loop, and see how it goes.

Comment: The avatar info is being pulled from the column "avatar" in one of the database fields. The query joins three tables together and is VERY long... the recordset is specific to that query, and additional information is being displayed below this dependent upon that query. I don't see how I could just drop a (second?) instance of the query in here in place of the "do" statement. Is it not possible to include an in/else statement within a do statement and have it "loop" successfully like everything else is?

Comment: I inserted the code you offered above (below the DO, because I wasn't sure where to put it??) It caused only the first record to be returned with two instances of a default avatar side by side. I can't change the DO loop without reprogramming the whole thing and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I just don't understand why this part of the code would echo the href and the alt image but NOT the img src the second and third times around?: echo '<a href="profile.php?u='.$row_Recordset1['username'].'"><img src="user/'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$row_Recordset1['username'].'" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;"></a>';

Comment: OK... this is weird. I echoed $avatar in the repeating field. Apparently, the avatar result 757655830.jpg, which is the file name in the "avatar" field in my table for the FIRST record returned is showing up for EACH record. It is repeating the same avatar information over and over again for each subsequent record and I'm not sure why. All of the other information in each subsequent record is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to shorten the whole thing a little bit. Maybe the following is helpful:

```
<p>
<?php
while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
  $av=$row_Recordset1['avatar'];
  $usrn=$row_Recordset1['username'];
  echo "<a href='profile.php?u=$usrn'><img class='avatar' src='"
       .($av>''?"user/$usr/$av":"images/avatardefault.jpg")."' alt='$usrn'></a>";
} ?>  </p>
```

In your previous form of the `while`-loop you are referencing the elements of the `$row_Recordset1`-array before it was filled for the first time. Now the while statement comes *before* the actual loop.

The former condition of `$avatar===Null` is now used in a negated way and requires a string longer than '' to exist, before the avatar is pulled from that variable.

In my version I have not included the `style` attribute but defined the class `avatar` instead since the formatting should preferably be done through an appropriate style directive in the CSS section. But that is surely a matter of taste. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to move the internal pointer because if i remember well, mysql_fetch_assoc does not move the pointer.

Use mysql data seek: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

BTW you should move to mysqli or pdo. Mysql library is deprecated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php - it does move the internal pointer when called.